# Fields being hidden in landscape mode in Android layout

Tags: android, layout, scroll

When I changes my layout from portrait to landscape mode some field in upper section of the activity are not visible. the code of my layout is as follows.
I have done a lot of research but never found any solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"       

    android:layout_width="match_parent"   
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.source.administrator.servemycar.Service_Detail">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:title="Zolito"
        android:background="@drawable/act"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
        android:visibility="visible"


        />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <include layout="@layout/content_service__detail" />       
   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the cont_layout.xml file of my code. The above two fields code and name with their respective fields are missing in landscape mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="40dp"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:rowCount="200"
android:columnCount="7"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:accessibilityLiveRegion="none"
android:layoutMode="clipBounds"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_marginRight="4dp">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CODE"
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NAME"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="1"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PHONE"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="E-MAIL"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REG.NO."
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_row="8"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:id="@+id/regno"
    android:layout_row="8"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REG.DATE"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_row="9"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/regdate"
    android:layout_row="9"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/regbtn"
    android:layout_row="9"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="VEH. TYPE"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_row="23"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/vehicle_type"
    android:layout_row="23"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="VEH.MAKE"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_row="26"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/vehicle_make"
    android:layout_row="26"
    android:layout_column="2"
    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MODEL"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_row="27"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_row="27"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NEXT SERVICE DATE"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_row="29"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_rowSpan="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/renewel_date_pol"
    android:layout_row="33"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/renewel_pol"
    android:layout_row="33"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REMARKS"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_row="34"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/renewel_date_service"
    android:layout_row="29"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/renewl_service"
    android:layout_row="29"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:src="@drawable/cal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NEXT INSURANCE DATE"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_row="31"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/renewel_date_insu"
    android:layout_row="31"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/renewel_insu"
    android:layout_row="31"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:src="@drawable/cal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" NEXT POLLUTION DATE"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_row="33"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_row="34"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:layout_rowSpan="6"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_row="40"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:background="#5b5b5b"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Which element is missing from the above layout file? Have you tried having two different layout files - one for portrait and one for landscape?

Comment: i have added the code for the content.xml file as well. please check @ucsunil

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried to create a landscape layout? Remember to place your objects using DP in your size and positioning properties, for margin and/or paddings also to keep the position relative to the screen.

Comment: may i know how to create that one as i am new to android.

Comment: May i know what you suggest. Should i create different layout for both orientations @Caio Lucas